# Android 2.2.1 textbox background image

Tags: android, html, css, image, background

We have a search icon in our textbox as background image. But when we press the textbox (so the focus is on it) then this background disappears. This problem only occurs on Android (v.2.2.1). What causes it and how can we solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to define the background image, and the code (if any) for the onFocus event of the TextView?

Comment: CSS:
`#q { background-image: url(/media/images/search.png); }`

But we don't use JavaScript. Weird...

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this isn't an Android issue, but a WebKit/HTML/CSS issue.

You could do a simple workaround by adding a CSS definition like this one:

```
#q:focus { background-image: url(/media/images/search.png); }
```

Comment: On what device is this behavior apparent?